# Number of days between past date and current date in Google spreadsheet

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, datediff

I want to calculate the number of days passed between past date and a current date. My past date is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I have used below mentioned formulas but giving the proper output.

```
=DAYS360(A2,TODAY())
=MINUS(D2,TODAY())
```

In the above formula `A2` = `4/12/2012` (dd/mm/yyyy) and I am not sure whether TODAY returns in `dd/mm/yyyy` format or not. I have tried using 123 button on the tool bar, but no luck.

Comment: (my first comment reflected to a section of the question that has been [edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14183512/revisions) since)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`DAYS360` does **not** calculate what you want, i.e. the number of days passed between the two dates – see the end of this post for details.

`MINUS()` should work fine, just not how you tried but the other way round:

```
=MINUS(TODAY(),D2)
```

You may also use simple subtraction (`-`):

```
=TODAY()-D2
```

I made [an updated copy of @DrCord’s sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArgUEpK3Wj2tdFBHZEJTejZNcnRXc1dDVXY0M1N3TkE) to illustrate this.

> Are you SURE you want DAYS360? That is a specialized function used in the
> financial sector to simplify calculations for bonds. It assumes a 360 day
> year, with 12 months of 30 days each. If you really want actual days, you'll
> lose 6 days each year.
> [[source]](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/days360-function-problem-t1767018.html#post5258664)

Comment: It would be more helpful to write the formula in your answer

Comment: @BenWheeler Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my old answer

Answer (score 49):

This worked for me:

```
=DATEDIF(B2, Today(), "D")
```

Comment: Documentation with more examples of DATEDIF can be found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en).

Keep in mind that you may need to format the cell to be a number (by default it seems to output a date.)
"Format" (from top level menu) > "Number" > "More Formats" > "Custom number formats" > "0"

Comment: thats the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the top Google answer for this, and it was way easier than I expected, here is the simple answer. Just subtract date1 from date2.

If this is your spreadsheet dates

```
     A            B
1 10/11/2017  12/1/2017
```

`=(B1)-(A1)`

results in 51, which is the number of days between a past date and a current date in Google spreadsheet

As long as it is a date format Google Sheets recognizes, you can directly subtract them and it will be correct.

To do it for a current date, just use the `=TODAY()` function.

`=TODAY()-A1`

While today works great, you can't use a date directly in the formula, you should referencing a cell that contains a date.

`=(12/1/2017)-(10/1/2017)` results in 0.0009915716411, not 61.

Comment: this method is (and was) already mentioned in my accepted answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

I used your idea, and found the difference and then just divided by 365 days.  Worked a treat.

```
=MINUS(F2,TODAY())/365
```

Then I shifted my cell properties to not display decimals.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the two formulas at the same time, it will not work...
Here is a simple spreadsheet with it working:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiOy0YDBXjt4dDJSQWg1Qlp6TEw5SzNqZENGOWgwbGc
If you are still getting problems I would need to know what type of erroneous result you are getting.

Today() returns a numeric integer value: Returns the current computer system date. The value is updated when your document recalculates. TODAY is a function without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. Kindly note that TODAY() must **NOT** be the first argument in the function otherwise it will not work.

```
=DATEDIF( W2, TODAY(), "d")
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Today() does return value in DATE format.
2. Select your "Days left field" and paste this formula in the field
   =DAYS360(today(),C2)
3. Go to Format > Number > More formats >Custom number format and select the number with no decimal numbers.

I tested, it works, at least in new version of Sheets, March 2015.